# Website still shows up when I shut down the server in AWS, Nodejs Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I'm using React-ecommerce, nodejs and express. I'm using an EC2-Instance on AWS. So, when I go to ghostnft.tech, it says "Hello World", when my server is working. Even if the server is running on port 8080 and I don't open ghostnft.tech:8080. I don't know why this is happening but it works, so it's good. The problem is, when I shut down the server, it still says "Hello World" on the website. How can that be? And even now after two days the server is shut down, it still works. And when I update the server so it should say "Hello World!", it doesn't update on the website. Plus, when I first started the server and connected everything on AWS, when I go to the public IPv4-DNS address, but then with "ec2-2.32.example.aws.amazon.com:8080", it gave me from 2 out of 3 refreshes a "502 Bad Gateway". On ghostnft.tech it gave me everytime the 502. Then, after about 3 hours there wasn't any 502 on ghostnft.tech and it worked. What happened here?
Below you see my index.js, that is like the server.js.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });
const createCheckoutSession = require('./api//checkout');
const webhook = require('./api/webhook');

const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log('server listening on port', port));

server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000;
server.headersTimeout = 70000;

app.use(express.json({
    verify: (req, res, buffer) => req['rawBody'] = buffer,
}));

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));

app.use(cors(corsOptions)) // Use this after the variable declaration

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!!!'));

app.post('/create-checkout-session', createCheckoutSession);

app.post('/webhook', webhook);
```

And because of the 502 I tried this, but the website won't update:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });
const createCheckoutSession = require('./api//checkout');
const webhook = require('./api/webhook');

const app = express();
const port = 8080;
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log('server listening on port', port));

server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000;
server.headersTimeout = 70000;

app.use(express.json({
    verify: (req, res, buffer) => req['rawBody'] = buffer,
}));

const corsOptions = {
   origin:'*',
   credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
   optionSuccessStatus:200,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions)) // Use this after the variable declaration

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!!!'));

app.post('/create-checkout-session', createCheckoutSession);

app.post('/webhook', webhook);
```

Comment: What do your log files say? Also, you mentioned react, I am assuming none of the endpoints you mentioned are of react but only of your nodejs server

Comment: Where can I see the log files? I'm sorry, the React is from the website, and the React website tries to connect to the named server.